# Images appearing in all browsers but IE?

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer

I just completed an html email for work, and everything works great...except for in IE. The image at the top of the page appears in all of the browsers except for IE. Personally, I've checked it in IE in all past versions up through 10, and it appears on my browser, but my boss is saying it is not showing up on his. (he has ie 8 installed, so can't check up past that) He would like it to work on IE 8.

Why would images not show up in internet explorer, but appear in all other browsers? I've heard of issues with positioning and certain css styles, but never images just not appearing.

This is the test of the email:
http://laurelsprings.staging.wpengine.com/email/tls/2013-fall/index2.html

Comment: Is this an email or a webpage? It's not quite clear.

Comment: It is an email that I have constructed on a staging site so my boss can review it before sending it out. Nothing fancy, all html and css on the same page.

Comment: FYI your document type declaration is not correct.  It should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` not `<!DOCTYPE html />` (no '/')

Comment: That's what I figured, the basic template was constructed by a previous employee. I need to go through and check for errors etc.

Comment: Try placing the first `<td>` in a `<tr>`.  There's also an extraneous `</p>` below the the `</ul>`.  I also don't believe any of the `colspan=3` attributes are necessary.

Comment: I hate working with tables, but this is how I was instructed to go about doing so lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use "display:table" in the image style. IE doesn't like it.

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought. I was just removing that and going to ask if that is the cause. Will report back in a minute.

Comment: I removed it and all is working fine. IE8 and above are supposed to support display:table; (or so I was reading online), I guess not tho